# Query returns only 4 out of 12 values of my table. Why is this happening?

Tags: performance, asp-classic, is-empty

I have created a script which I am using on 2 different system. One is Windows 10 with SQL Server Express 2019 and the other is on Windows 7 (32bit) with SQL Server Express 2014. The db I am using has the same structure. The code I am using in ASP Classic is exactly the same on both machines! But in the win7 machine does not work as it should!

I am having a query to my db and the problem is that SOME of the values I am getting are empty. The code I am using is the following:

```
        <%
 Set rs21 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 strSQL21 = "SELECT * FROM otherfiles WHERE animalid LIKE '" & lngRecordNo & "'
 AND historyid LIKE '" & historyid & "' order by datedone DESC"

 rs21.Open strSQL21, adoCon
 %>
 BLAH BLAH BLAH
 <%
Do While not rs21.EOF
historyid = rs21("historyid")

if not historyid = "" then
Set rshis = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQLhis = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE id_no LIKE '" & historyid & "' order by id_no DESC"
rshis.Open strSQLhis, adoCon

 '------------------- if I remove the following line (Set rscol) it works fine ---------------------------
Set rscol = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strcol = "SELECT * FROM hospitals WHERE id_no = "& rsGuestbook21("hosid") &" order by id_no DESC"
rscol.Open strcol, adocon
color = rscol("color")
%>

     BLAH BLAH BLAH

    <%=rs21("datedone")%> ---> empty value
    <%=rs21("id_no")%> ---> works fine!!!
```

I am 100% sure that my table has its values. In fact as I mention above only but setting the `rscol = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` then the values becomes ??empty??. Commenting this line works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my ??mistake??...

Not really sure if it is a mistake thou... but the problem solved when I placed a field that had a DATA TYPE of "nvarchar(MAX)" at the end of my of my table! Weird stuff??? Do you think that there is something more than that in which I should investigate?